# Load a down server

Tags: javascript, server

I need to load/browse a (JavaScript based) website every day. But the server of this site remains down most of the time. So, I can't always browse this site.

**Now, my question:** How can I load this site even if it's server is down?

**EDIT:**
There is a registration process in this site. When this website is responsive, I filled up the information (i.e user name, email,phone,date of birth, address, country and so many...) and submit it. Then it check all the validation of registration process. If the passes all the validation then it returns a pdf file to download. but any validation fails don't return the pdf file to download.

In this case, can I cache all the web content and execute locally get the registration form as like as the server was responsive.

Additionally, should I run there any script?

Comment: eye of newt and toe of frog and other majicks - sorry about the sarcastic response, but, really? how to access a site when it's server that is down? the site is the server, the server is the site, it's like asking how do you buy milk from a shop that is closed

Comment: Depending on how the content is provided by the server, you may be able to separate the code/logic from the information/contents. Hosting the bulk of the code on a separate server, you'll be able to access the site. And, it can retrieve the info/contents from the problematic server when it's available, possibly caching the last successful response to support refreshing when it's offline/unresponsive.

Comment: @ Jonathan Lonowski  I hope the light of this words 'able to separate the code/logic from the information/contents'. Can you explain how can o do this? I have experience in Objective C for 5 years though  no in Java script

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the content of this page that you are trying to access does not have real-time dynamic content then you might want to explore some of the page caching services like Google web cache?

This site offers a variety of such services,
http://www.cachedpages.com/

Note that a cached page will not be up to date, you will have to check when it was last cached.

A typical use case for such service would be for example stackoverflow is currently down and my search engine returns me with a stackover page that might contain answer to my question. In such instance I will access the cached page to bypass the downtime.

Alternatively you might want to write a small script to do a "curl" command and try to fetch content of the troublesome web server and cache it locally on your own computer so that when it goes down you can lookup the most recently cached version in your own comp.

Comment: thanks for you reply. it is very near  the solution of my question

Comment: but i need to clarify more

Comment: this is a portal site. i  need to register in this site frequently. so , google cache will not solve my problem.

Comment: may be you said about 'curl'. i think this will be the great solution for me.

Comment: Assuming you are on linux platform you can do "curl https://egghead.io/ > test.html" to grab a html page off from a web server, the arrow command is just to say; output the html content to a file call test.html on my local drive. 

Now all you need is to write a script in python or perl and then create a crontab job (scheduler) to poll the webserver once every 3-5 minutes. Your script can should probably also store a datetime stamp of its last successful fetch to track its last retrieval.

Comment: i have a programming language. So, can you help me on about this.

Comment: I don't quite understand on the "need to register in this site frequently" do you mean logging into it?

Comment: this is a web portal site. every day many people comes to me and say for register for him. as this is a lengthy process general people can do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, from what I know is that not all sites are the same in handling their registration process. I think you might want to read up the POST request section of the curl command.

But to begin with... You might first want to look at the HTML page source of the registration page to see if there is any hint on how a request (registration) is put through to their web server.

Comment: yes, in source there such code. I need to execute this "post" command locally

Comment: No worries. If you think CURL is the answer to your issue then i'll greatly  appreciate if u can mark this as answered. Thanks!